# Need help creating a dynamic phone number detector?

Tags: database, contacts, phone-number

Here's the situation: users of my app are going to create their account using their phone number only (like WhatsApp for example). So no username, password or anything like that. I'll be storing those phone numbers in my database after verification, so I know all the stored numbers will be in one specific format.

The tricky part, however, is that I want my app to look through my users' contacts to see if their contacts have an account on my app's server. In theory, I just wanted the app to check the phone number and see if it exists in my database, because I'm pretty sure the phone number is the only (unique) property of a contact my app will have access to (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The thing I'm afraid of is that every smartphone owner stores the phone number of a contact in their own way. What I mean by this is that for example, one person might store the phone number of a contact in a 'clean way', with the country code and area code and everything else that should be in a phone number, like this: +1 xxx xxx xxxx (I'm from The Netherlands and I'm just guessing, so my apologies to all the American readers if this is NOT what an American phone number looks like). Some other person might store the phone number of his contact the 'quick way', without any country codes or area codes, like this: xxx xxx xxxx (no country code) or even xxx xxxx (no area code).

This would already be an issue in one country (the USA for example), not to mention the situation in which someone has contacts from other countries (with their own area code rules) in his phone. The contact in a person's contact list still might be using my app with their phone number, but if that person stored his contact's phone number in the 'quick way' my app wouldn't be able to find it in the database. Right now, I'm either looking for an alternate unique value of a contact which I can also store in my database to use that as the identifier instead (I highly doubt that exists though), or preferably a way to make the app search a little more dynamically, so that it would identify a matching phone number even if the number stored in the contacts list isn't identical to the phone number stored in my database.

Rather than some technical advice, I'd rather hear from someone who knows a thing or two about phone numbers around the world. For instance: would it be smart to just search for the last 8 digits of a contact's phone number instead, or would that be risky in terms of a possible duplicate phone number elsewhere in the world? Just wondering what the safest way is to go about this...

By the way: the app I'm building is written in Swift 3, and I'll be accessing the contacts of a user through Apple's Contacts Framework.

Comment: Please tell me you're warning your users that you're siphoning off their friends/family/coworkers' contact information before doing so?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not siphoning anything or anyone. The only thing getting access to the contacts' numbers is the app (using Apple's own permission prompt), to compare it to stored data. It doesn't do anything else with the numbers, so that means it doesn't store it or pass it to someone else either. Simply put, no human (including myself) will ever have access to the user's contacts information. Sure, I'll let my users choose whether or not their contacts can see if the user is using my app, but other than that I do nothing different from any other invite-compatible social app in the world.

Comment: @ceejayoz Or are you telling me you had to give WhatsApp permission to let any of your contacts just send you a WhatsApp message from the moment you created a profile on that app? If you did, you might have downloaded the wrong app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique codes are tricky - especially when based on real-world data (which is generally pretty noisy and with more exceptions that you can think of).

I agree that "last 8 digits" would be very risky.
Instead what I'd do is figure out (or guess) what country the user comes from, and always store that with the phone number (even if the user doesn't choose to display it).

So lets say that if they have an address with a country - then use that country's country-code. If they don't, then have a "default" country (USA is oft-used, though I really hate that (I'm from Australia).

Be aware you will still get errors and exceptions, but it means you can make an educated guess if 9123 4567 is the same as (+61) 9123 4567.

Also be aware of things like:

1. sometimes more than one person shares a phone number
2. sometimes a person has more than one phone number

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention that, but yes, I am asking my users to give up their country, and I'm even asking for a region in case they're giving up a country which has multiple area codes within that country (most of them do). Nevertheless, it doesn't solve my problem, because it's still the CONTACTS' numbers that I have to search for, not my USERS' number. Even if someone from New York would sign up for my app, he could still have a contact which either lives in Paris or in Mumbai (which both have totally different numbers)...

Comment: See, my app has no way of knowing in what country someone's contact lives, so it doesn't know what country the phone number it's comparing belongs to. I'll just go with the 7 digits method (since that's the minimum amount for any phone number around the globe). First, look for the last 7 digits and then see if there's any prefixes before those 7 digits to be sure it matches.

Comment: By the way, in response of the two warnings you gave me: I also store the device my app is installed on, so a shared number can only run my app on one device at a time. And multiple phone numbers don't matter, since I'm really just looking for the number in my database and not the contact. If I would find a matching number, all the other numbers of that contact could just be ignored.

Comment: "my app has no way of knowing in what country someone's contact lives" yes... you can only guess, based on the suggestions I've made (and you've already mentioned). You could add a confirmation screen for the person running the app... but beyond that there really isn't more that you can do.